# Access Denied Error when executing VBoxManage during Test Kitchen's kitchen converge Ubuntu 22

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, vagrant, chef

I am encountering an error while trying to execute the kitchen converge command in Test Kitchen (v3.1.0) for my infrastructure testing. The error occurs during the creation of a virtual machine using the `virtualbox` provider.

Error Message:

```
-----> Starting Test Kitchen (v3.1.0)
-----> Creating <testing-full-test-ubuntu-1804>...
       Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
       ==> default: Importing base box 'bento/ubuntu-18.04'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
       ==> default: Checking if box 'bento/ubuntu-18.04' version '202303.13.0' is up to date...
       ==> default: Setting the name of the VM: kitchen-testing-full-test-ubuntu-1804-23e12752-8f23-4345-8e22-ed5151f2f3b4
       ==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
       There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
       for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.
       
       Command: ["hostonlyif", "ipconfig", "vboxnet14", "--ip", "172.28.128.1", "--netmask", "255.255.255.0"]
       
       Stderr: VBoxManage: error: Code E_ACCESSDENIED (0x80070005) - Access denied (extended info not available)
       VBoxManage: error: Context: "EnableStaticIPConfig(Bstr(pszIp).raw(), Bstr(pszNetmask).raw())" at line 242 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp
```

### Issue description:

I am facing an issue while running the kitchen converge command in Test Kitchen. This error occurs during the creation of a virtual machine with the name `testing-full-test-ubuntu-1804` using the `virtualbox` provider.

The error message suggests that the problem lies with executing the VBoxManage command, which is responsible for controlling VirtualBox through Vagrant. Specifically, the `["hostonlyif", "ipconfig", "vboxnet14", "--ip", "172.28.128.1", "--netmask", "255.255.255.0"]` command encounters an access denial.

### Error details:

- Error code: `E_ACCESSDENIED (0x80070005)`
- Error context: `EnableStaticIPConfig(Bstr(pszIp).raw(), - Bstr(pszNetmask).raw())" at line 242 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp`

Any suggestions or guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To solve the issue, I followed the instructions outlined in the VirtualBox [documentation](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly). According to the guide, I added the following line to the `/etc/vbox/networks.conf` file: network `* 0.0.0.0/0 ::/0`. This step helped me resolve the problem I was facing

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).